# Play framework, Akka: actor communication with controller

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, akka, actor

In short - I'm building a Scala/Play application which will monitor certain files/folders for changes and use Server Sent Events to push data to the browser.

I'm using [Swatch](https://github.com/mcaserta/swatch) library to do the monitoring which launches with application. This is my `Global` object. It starts the monitoring by launching a worker actor (as far as I understand) and reports if there are any changes - it's working just fine:

```
import akka.actor.{Props, ActorSystem}
import play.api._
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Akka
import play.api.Play.current
import include.Swatch._
import include.SwatchActor

object Global extends GlobalSettings {

    override def onStart(app: Application) {
        Logger.info("Application has started")
        val swatch = Akka.system.actorOf(Props[SwatchActor])
        swatch ! Watch("/folder/path", Seq(Create, Modify, Delete), true)
    }

}
```

At the moment whenever a change happens the `swatch` actor just outputs this to the console:

```
[INFO] [02/14/2014 11:45:04.377] [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://application/deadLetters] Message [include.Swatch$Create] from Actor[akka://application/deadLetters] to Actor[akka://application/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

This is my controller (so far it's not doing much):

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._

object Application extends Controller {

    def index = Action {
        Ok("index")
    }

}
```

The browser should establish a connection with the controller and then whenever my worker actor detects a change, server push to the browser happens. My problem so far is: how do I get my worker actor to send messages to my `index` action in the controller? Would the approach I've described above work at all?

**UPDATE:** I'll be using websockets to communicate with the browser. Another important thing - the worker actor must be running all the time despite of if there is an established communication with the browser or not.

**UPDATE2:** Thanks to drexin and others I've managed to scrape together a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21851444/scala-play-akka-websocket-how-to-pass-actor-messages-through-websocket/21859404#21859404).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What do you use for the communication between your app and the browser? Long polling, websockets?

In general I expect the `SwatchActor` to notify the sender of the `Watch` message when a change happens. As you send the message from outside of an actor, the sender will be `noSender` and thus the notifications will end up in the `deadLetters`. What you have to do is create an actor that receives the notifications and pushes them to the users either through a websocket or something similar.

Comment: I'll be using websockets. So I assume I need to create an actor in my `index` method that will be receiving messages from my worker? How do I do that? Isn't the worker actor out of controller's context in my case?

Comment: You should create an actor whenever a client connects to the websocket, because that will be the communication channel between the client and the server. Whenever this actor then receives an event from the swatch actor, it can just push a message to the websocket.

Comment: Right. So how do I create an actor in my `index` method and make it receive messages from the swatch actor? I'm fairly new to Akka, so the implementation is still a little fussy for me.

Comment: Then I would suggest you to read the Akka dos first: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/scala.html. But essentially you will just have to write an actor class that can handle those messages and pushed the updates to the websocket.

Comment: Thanks, I've been reading it, that's why I've raised this question. The point is: I understand how to do this if I launched both swatch (worker/monitoring) actor and actor that handles the messages if both of them were inside `index` method, but that won't work for me. I need the swatch actor to launch with the application (hence it's in the Global object), so the question is - can the message handling actor which I'd create in my `index` method even communicate with swatch actor which is inside `Global` object?

Comment: Yes, each actor has an actor path and you can retrieve an `ActorSelection` by calling `system.actorSelection(path)`. You can then send messages to this `ActorSelection` as you would to a normal `ActorRef`.